# How to override osgi config for OOTB component partially?

Tags: java, configuration, osgi, aem

I want to override standart osgi cq component configuration for

```
com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.xml
```

Default configuration is fine for me but I want to change only one option.

I don't want to override full configuration but override only single option(minify should be set as false) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per the documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-3/deploying/configuring_osgi.html#par_text_15), it should be fine to create a configuration node & only override the value that you wish to change:

> For each parameter that you want to configure create a property on
>   this node:
>
> - **Name:** the parameter name as shown in the Felix Console; the name is
>     shown in brackets at the end of the field description. For example,
>     for Create Version on Activation use
>     `versionmanager.createVersionOnActivation`
> - **Type:** as appropriate.
> - **Value:**
>     as required.
>
> **You only need to create properties for the parameters that you want to configure, others will still take the default values as set by CQ.** *[emphasis mine]*

Just make sure not to override values with blank defaults, e.g.:

```
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"     
          xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
          cq.homeaclsetup.privileges.user="jcr:all"/>
```

Should leave the `cq.homeaclsetup.privileges.group` value at its default, as it hasn't been included in the config node at all.

As far as I'm aware though, it will choose the default value *for the component*, rather than the default value for AEM — there could be an out-of-the-box OSGi config node in the `libs/` folder that you may override, so be careful of this.

In that case, you'd need to copy config into your node so that it is not lost.

Answer (score 1):

Create a node named "com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl" under /apps/system/config and make changes as you need